# BIP > Getting Hours and Minutes from a date

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

In my xml I have a date like "08/21/2011 18:17:52" and I need it's hours and minutes in AM/PM format like "08/21/2011 18:17:52" will be 06:17 PM. I tried setting format on from the template itself in the "Formatting" section.
I tried following:

1. Tried setting format in BIP rtf template designer

[image]

2. Tried to format like below:

But it did not work.

I am attaching sample [xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z86ug4cxy5y40qu/BIP%20Action.xml?dl=0) and [rtf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xer3kmqk5ogtvan/Calendar%20Daily%20-%20Copy.rtf?dl=0).

Please guide me how can I get the hour and minutes part.

I want the output like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the solution of my problem.

1. Include below line on the rtf:

> `<?namespace:psfn=http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/com.siebel.xmlpublisher.reports.XSLFunctions?>`

2. Get the required time as below:

> `<?psfn:getCanonicalDate(PlannedCompletion)?>`

Answer (score 1):

Date data in the XML needs to look something like this in order to be formatted with BI Publisher:

```
<DATE_ELEMENT>2012-07-31T14:14:51.000+00:00</DATE_ELEMENT>
```

From the XML Publisher Administration and Developers Guide:

> The data engine generates date elements using the canonical ISO date
>   format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM for a mapped date element.

Comment: Second that. In this case, the source system is Siebel , and IMHO, it is responding with Siebel standard date format: MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: @Edhayes3 yes you are right but now i am not having date in this format. Any solution on this please?

Comment: Similar to your other post, you'll need to edit the way the XML is generated. From a quick search, might have to edit the Siebel Integration Object.

Comment: @EdHayes3, your answers are not quite helping me as i see you don't have any relevant expertise.. I found the solution and posting it as answer. I am afraid your guess work may direct someone wasting time by working on wrong directions..